# Keep only first line with matching pattern

Tags: bash, sed, cat

Does anyone know how I can search a file for a string, then delete all lines except for the one with the first occurrence of the pattern?

E.g., from

```
sheep
cow
pig
pig
goat
```

to

```
pig
```

where `pig` is the first line with that pattern.

I know how to delete lines that don't contain a pattern:

```
sed -i -e '/PATTERN/!d' file
```

No idea how to only keep the first occurrence, though.

Comment: `grep pattern file | head 1`?

Comment: or even better `grep -m1 pattern file | sponge file`

Comment: @daniu You've got a typo there. I'm pretty sure you meant `head -1` (or equivalently, `head -n 1`), since `head 1` will attempt to open a file named `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tell sed to [quit](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Quitting) after the first match:

```
sed -i '/pig/!d;q' infile
```

This works because when `d` is hit, the rest of the commands is ignored, so `q` will only be executed after the first match.

Or you could use the [`-m`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002dm) option of grep (works for both GNU and BSD grep, but isn't required by POSIX):

```
grep -m1 'pig' infile > infile.tmp && mv infile.tmp infile
```

Comment: Since you already know what the contents of the file should be, you can just write it yourself if `grep` succeeds: `grep -q pig infile && echo pig > infile`.

Comment: @chepner True, but for anything less trivial, for example where the pattern doesn't match the complete line, that'd break.